# Magento errors not writing errors to var/report after migration

Tags: magento-enterprise, error, magento-1.14, error-log

My last error was on : Sep  5 11:31 947043863198

I just noticed it and have no clue why it's not working. I checked the admin panel in system > configuration > developer and made sure the log settings were set to "enabled" YES

system log file name = system.log

exceptions log file name = exception.log

Why can't i see my errors in the var/report?

permissions on that report folder:
rwxrwx---+  2 user user 4096 Sep  5 11:35 report

Comment: Did you check the permission on var/report? You may also want to check you server temp folders (i.e /tmp)

Comment: where is the server temp folders and i'll check now... updated above with permissions.. have a look.. looks good to me.. read write execute

Comment: tmp folder in root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
system > configuration > developer -> log settings -> Enabled set to YES
```

This settings are only for logs and it will allow system to create log in `var/log` folder with `system.log` and `exception.log` files.

In `var/report` folder system will generate fatal error reports. And above settings not used for `var/report`.

Comment: It's not generating reports in var/report, fatal error reports not working. any idea why? this is the main problem. I need this to work correctly so i may debug.

Comment: do you have sufficient permission to var folder. or for testing you can rename addCss  function in class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head and see what error coming in frontend and check it will generate report or not.

Comment: it appears so, i posted my permissions for that folder above.

Comment: means after testing as I mention above, is it showing error report number or showing error directly on page?

Comment: I'm going to test that now.

Comment: Yes it threw and error and I saw it in the var/report.  There has been an error processing your request
Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addCss(Array
(
    [0] => css/styles.css
)
)

Comment: So your error reports are working fine :)

Comment: yessir.. i guess i may have thought of the system.log file. Is there a way to test that? I'm still going to mark your answer as correct. Thank you.  =]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29946/discussion-between-supplement-and-akhilesh-patel).